# How can I change the present image of the button to another image on button press in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my home screen of the app, I have two buttons, If the user selects a button the touched response is to be shown by changing its present image into another I tried all the methods of setting state and passing conditions but it's not working

Here is my code MainScreen.js file:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar, Image, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

class MainScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    computerPressed: false,
    teamPressed: true
  }
  render() {
return (
  <Image
  source={require('./Images/bg_img.png')}
  style={styles.backgroundStyle} >

  <StatusBar hidden />

    <Image
    source={require('./Images/History.png')}
    style={styles.historybuttonStyle} />

    <Image
    source={require('./Images/logo_ws.png')}
    style={styles.logoStyle} />

<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => Actions.screen2({ challenge: 'Computer' })}
onPressIn={this.state.computerPressed = true}
onPressOut={this.state.computerPressed}>
    <Image
    source={require(this.state.computerPressed ? './Images/landing-bnt1-on.png' : './Images/landing-bnt1.png')}
    style={styles.landingbnt1Style} />
</TouchableHighlight>

<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => Actions.screen2({ challenge: 'Team' })}
onPressIn={this.state.teamPressed = true}
onPressOut={this.state.teamPressed}>
    <Image
    source={require(this.state.computerPressed ? './Images/landing-bnt2-on.png' : './Images/landing-bnt2.png')}
    style={styles.landingbnt2Style} />
</TouchableHighlight>

</Image>
);
}
}
const styles = {

 backgroundStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    position: 'relative'
  },
  logoStyle: {
    flex: 0,
    width: 340,
    height: 270,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    marginBottom: 150,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 50
  },
  historybuttonStyle: {
    width: 38,
    height: 35,
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 5,
    top: 10
  },
  landingbnt1Style: {
    width: 250,
    height: 45,
    top: 175
  },
  landingbnt2Style: {
    width: 250,
    height: 45,
    top: 200
  }
};
export default MainScreen;
```

and I have this error pop up when I executed this code:

[image: 1st error]

and when i changed my code to this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar, Image, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const a = require('./Images/landing-bnt1-on.png');
const b = require('./Images/landing-bnt1.png');
const c = require('./Images/landing-bnt2-on.png');
const d = require('./Images/landing-bnt2.png');

class MainScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    computerPressed: false,
    teamPressed: true
  }
  render() {
return (
  <Image
  source={require('./Images/bg_img.png')}
  style={styles.backgroundStyle} >

  <StatusBar hidden />

    <Image
    source={require('./Images/History.png')}
    style={styles.historybuttonStyle} />

    <Image
    source={require('./Images/logo_ws.png')}
    style={styles.logoStyle} />

<TouchableHighlight
onPress={() => Actions.screen2({ challenge: 'Computer' })}
onPressIn={this.state.computerPressed = true}
onPressOut={this.state.computerPressed}>
    <Image
    source={require(this.state.computerPressed ? a : b)}
    style={styles.landingbnt1Style} />
</TouchableHighlight>

<TouchableHighlight
onPress={() => Actions.screen2({ challenge: 'Team' })}
onPressIn={this.state.teamPressed = true}
onPressOut={this.state.teamPressed}>
    <Image
    source={require(this.state.computerPressed ? c : d)}
    style={styles.landingbnt2Style} />
</TouchableHighlight>

</Image>
);
}
}
const styles = {

 backgroundStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    position: 'relative'
  },
  logoStyle: {
    flex: 0,
    width: 340,
    height: 270,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    marginBottom: 150,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 50
  },
  historybuttonStyle: {
    width: 38,
    height: 35,
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 5,
    top: 10
  },
  landingbnt1Style: {
    width: 250,
    height: 45,
    top: 175
  },
  landingbnt2Style: {
    width: 250,
    height: 45,
    top: 200
  }
};
export default MainScreen;
```

this is the error pop up :

[image: 2nd-error]

SO how can i get this functionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem hope it helps for others

I have changed from TouchableHighlight to TouchableWithoutFeedback

and made few changes as suggested as answers thank you @Val

So here's my code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StatusBar, Image, TouchableWithoutFeedback } from 'react-native';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const a = require('./Images/landing-bnt1-on.png');
const b = require('./Images/landing-bnt1.png');
const c = require('./Images/landing-bnt2-on.png');
const d = require('./Images/landing-bnt2.png');

class MainScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    computerPressed: false,
    teamPressed: false
  }
  render() {
return (
  <Image
  source={require('./Images/bg_img.png')}
  style={styles.backgroundStyle} >

  <StatusBar hidden />

    <Image
    source={require('./Images/History.png')}
    style={styles.historybuttonStyle} />

    <Image
    source={require('./Images/logo_ws.png')}
    style={styles.logoStyle} />

<TouchableWithoutFeedback
onPress={() => {
  Actions.screen2({ challenge: 'Computer' });
  }
}
onPressIn={() => {
    this.setState({ computerPressed: true });
  }
}
onPressOut={() => {
    this.setState({ computerPressed: false });
}
} >
    <Image
    source={this.state.computerPressed ? a : b}
    style={styles.landingbnt1Style} />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>

<TouchableWithoutFeedback
onPress={() => {
  Actions.screen2({ challenge: 'Team' });
  }
}
onPressIn={() => {
    this.setState({ teamPressed: true });
  }
}
onPressOut={() => {
    this.setState({ teamPressed: false });
}
} >
    <Image
    source={this.state.teamPressed ? c : d}
    style={styles.landingbnt2Style} />
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>

</Image>
);
}
}
const styles = {

 backgroundStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    width: undefined,
    height: undefined,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    position: 'relative'
  },
  logoStyle: {
    flex: 0,
    width: 340,
    height: 270,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    marginBottom: 150,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 50
  },
  historybuttonStyle: {
    width: 38,
    height: 35,
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 5,
    top: 10
  },
  landingbnt1Style: {
    width: 250,
    height: 45,
    top: 175
  },
  landingbnt2Style: {
    width: 250,
    height: 45,
    top: 200
  }
};
export default MainScreen;
```

Answer (score 2):

there are several rules you have to follow with react-native:

### Images cannot be conditionally `require`:

```js
<Image
    source={require(this.state.computerPressed ? './Images/landing-bnt1-on.png' : './Images/landing-bnt1.png')}
    style={styles.landingbnt1Style} />
```

this statement is not valid. that's why you got your first error message `Unknown named module: '../images/landing-btn1-on.png'`.

instead, load image statically:

```js
const image_btn1 = require('./Images/landing-btn1.png');
const image_btn1_on = require('./Images/landing-btn1-on.png');
```

and conditionally switching between them.

```js
<Image
    source={this.state.computerPressed ? image_btn1_on : image_btn1}
    style={styles.landingbnt1Style} />
```

### JSX Function should be valid:

JSX function won't work with this pattern.

```js
onPressIn={this.state.computerPressed = true}
onPressOut={this.state.computerPressed}>
```

do this instead:

```js
onPressIn={() => { this.state.computerPressed = true }}
onPressOut={ () => { this.state.computerPressed = false }}>
```

And,

### You should always use `setState()` outside of constructor:

or `render()` won't get triggered.

so previous expression becomes:

```js
onPressIn={() => {
    this.setState({computerPressed: true });
}
onPressOut={ () => {
    this.setState({computerPressed: false });
}
```

Comment: ,hey it was very useful but still, I get the same error as i have mentioned above (Require unkown module 4.....)

Comment: there are two image places in your code, `Computer` and `Team`. did you change both of them?

Comment: I could run now but my buttons are not getting displayed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an issue or a conflict in your node_modules.

Try to delete node_modules folder and then run in your terminal

```
nom install
```

Comment: maybe he means delete node_modules & run "npm install" from command line from your project folder

Comment: I don't think that is the issue but I still tried doing that and it didn't change still the same error

Answer (score 0):

With version 0.63 React Native introduced a new core component [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) solving this problem:

```
   import { Pressable, Text, View } from 'react-native';

    <Pressable onPress={() => { alert("doSomething") }}>
      {({ pressed }) => (
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
          <Text> Toggle Image </Text>
          {pressed 
            ? <Image source={ require('../assets/img-pressed.png') } /> 
            : <Image source={ require('../assets/img.png') } />}
        </View>
      )}
    </Pressable>
```

You can also adjust the styles of the wrapper element by doing this:

```
    <Pressable onPress={() => { alert("doSomething") }} 
      style={({ pressed }) => [
      {
        backgroundColor : pressed
          ? 'red'
          : 'green'
      }
      ]}>
      {({ pressed }) => (
        <View style={styles.myCustomStyleWithoutBackgroundColor}>
          <Text> Toogle Image and Background Color </Text>
          {pressed 
            ? <Image source={ require('../assets/img-pressed.png') } /> 
            : <Image source={ require('../assets/img.png') } />}
        </View>
      )}
    </Pressable>
```